# How to show a password field as asterisks after a second in html

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am creating a login page with username and password. I created the password field as asterisks using "input type="password"", But i want to display the asterisk symbol after a second before that the raw character should be shown.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Some mobile devices (i.e. on Android) already do this by default on input fields with `type="password"`.

Comment: I want to implement this feature in my HTML web page

Answer (score 3):

You can use this plugin, its compatible with all devices.
https://blog.decaf.de/2009/07/07/iphone-like-password-fields-using-jquery/

Here is another solution, but this one doesn't hide the last character unless you blur from field.
http://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-1-the-masked-password-field/

```js
//apply masking to the demo-field
//pass the field reference, masking symbol, and character limit
new MaskedPassword(document.getElementById("demo-field"), '\u25CF');

//test the submitted value
document.getElementById('demo-form').onsubmit = function(){
 alert('pword = "' + this.pword.value + '"');
 return false;
};
```

```html
<script src="http://www.sitepoint.com/examples/password/MaskedPassword/MaskedPassword.js"></script>

<form id="demo-form" action="#">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="demo-field"><strong>This is a masked-password field.</strong> Type into the field to see the masking effect:</label>
        <span style="position: relative;">
        <input type="hidden" name="pword" value="sasasas">
        <input class="password masked" id="demo-field" value="" type="text" autocomplete="off">
        </span>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `input` field of type `text` initially. Later on in the `setTimeout`, you can change the type to `password` as shown below:

**HTML:**

```
<label>Password</label>
<input type="text" name="password" value="p@ssw0rd" />
```

**JS:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0].type = "password"
}, 1000);
```

Refer to the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/5a9fnzvq/) here.

Answer (score 0):

Using `setTimeout` in jQuery you may do the change `attr` from `type=text` to `password`. But this is not a good way.

You may use something as show below using `mouse-over/mouse-out`.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#method2").mouseover(function(){
        this.type = "text";
    }).mouseout(function(){
        this.type = "password";
    })
    
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="password" id="method2" value="" placeholder="Type in your password" /> Event using mouseover and mouseout
```

You may also do it the old way :

```js
//Place this plugin snippet into another file in your applicationb
(function ($) {
    $.toggleShowPassword = function (options) {
        var settings = $.extend({
            field: "#password",
            control: "#toggle_show_password",
        }, options);

        var control = $(settings.control);
        var field = $(settings.field)

        control.bind('click', function () {
            if (control.is(':checked')) {
                field.attr('type', 'text');
            } else {
                field.attr('type', 'password');
            }
        })
    };
}(jQuery));

//Here how to call above plugin from everywhere in your application document body
$.toggleShowPassword({
    field: '#test1',
    control: '#test2'
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Password:
<input type="password" id="test1" value="" placeholder="Type your password" />
<input id="test2" type="checkbox" />Show password
```

Source : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/herdiansc/dnznh/8/)